# how update value input form class result

Tags: php, class, oop

I Have a profile page and admin can edit profile users,
all process on one page done,How i can refresh and update value form data after success query update ?
User.class file :

```
class User {
...

    public function updateUser($id, $firstname, $lastname, $phone, $birthday, $managerid)
{
    $con = $this->DBconnect();
    $id = (int)$id;
    $managerid = $this->checkParam($managerid);
    $firstname = $firstname;
    $lastname = $lastname;;
    $mobile = $phone;
    $birthday = $this->checkParam($birthday);


    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `manager_id` = :manager_id,`firstname` = :firstname,`lastname` = :lastname,`birthday` = :birthday,`mobile` = :mobile WHERE `id` = :id";
    $result = $con->prepare($query);
    $result->BindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->BindParam(':manager_id', $managerid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->BindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $result->BindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
    $result->BindParam(':birthday', $birthday);
    $result->BindParam(':mobile', $mobile);

    $check = $result->execute();
        return true;


}}
```

profile.php file :

```
  <?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
}
$user = new User();
$user_info = $user->getuser($id);
while ($info = $user_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $firstname = $info['firstname'];
    $lastname = $info['lastname'];
    $mobile = $info['mobile'];
    $birthday = $info['birthday'];
    $managerid = $info['manager_id'];

}
$manager_ob = new Manager();
$managers = $manager_ob->getAllManager();
$managers_name = array();
while ($manager = $managers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $managers_list[] = $manager;

}
if (isset($_POST['edit-profile'])) {
    $update_result = $user->updateUser($_POST['user_id'],$_POST['user_firstname'],$_POST['user_lastname'],$_POST['user_mobile'],$_POST['user_birthday'],$_POST['manager_id']);
    if($update_result){
        echo 'Profile Edited';

    }
}
?>

  <form method="post" action="#" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID</label>

    <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php echo check_param($id); ?>"/></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Firstname</label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_firstname" value="<?php echo check_param($firstname); ?>" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lastname</label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_lastname" value="<?php echo check_param($lastname); ?>"/></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_mobile" value="<?php echo check_param($mobile); ?>"/></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="birthday">Birthday
                                        </label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input id="birthday" type="text" class="form-control" name="user_birthday"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Manager</label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control m-b" name="manager_id">

                                            <?php foreach ($managers_list as $managers_n) { ?>

                                                <option <?php if ($managers_n['id'] == $managerid) {
                                                    echo 'selected';
                                                } ?>
                                                    value="<?php echo $managers_n['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $managers_n['name']; ?></option>;
                                            <?php }
                                            ?>

                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" name="edit-profile" class="btn btn-block btn-w-m btn-success"
                                       value="Edit profile">
                            </form>
```

i load profile data after submit edit :

```
$update_result = $user->updateUser($_POST['user_id'],$_POST['user_firstname'],$_POST['user_lastname'],$_POST['user_mobile'],$_POST['user_birthday'],$_POST['manager_id']);
if($update_result){
    echo 'Profile Edited';

}
```

only display message Profile Edited but must be refresh page for renew data
I must  fetch again query for update values?  or have better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use Ajax for this this is probably the best way to change the data without refreshing. More info about (jQuery) ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Your other option is to force a refresh after the submit. You can do this in PHP like so:

```
Header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

I would suggest choosing ajax to tackle this problem though.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks,I thought about Ajax but i must create a handle page for ajax,Do can without a handle page use ajax this page?

Comment: It would be best to create a seperate "page" (called: a call) indeed. You can process the info and then echo it into the page. perhaps check out some tutorials on making ajax calls.

Comment: if this answer helped you, woudl you mind accepting it as correct answer? Thanks :)